# replace a single quote in a string with another single quote

Tags: java

I have a String with single quote. I want to replace the single quote with 2 single quotes.
I tried using

```
 String s="Kathleen D'Souza";

s.replaceAll("'","''");

s.replaceAll("\'","\'\'");

s.replace("'","''");

s.replace("\'","\'\'");
```

But the single quote is not getting replaced with 2 single quotes.

Comment: Why? I'm always very suspicious of questions like this. I usually find that they want to do things that don't need to be done.

Comment: I need to escape the single quote before using it in the hibernate query. Thats the reason was trying replace 2 single quotes

Comment: @EJP This is a very legitimate question.  Escaping SQL queries is always a good thing.  Until such time someone can move to a better technology where it is escaped automatically, one can only do string replacements.  OWASP top 10.

Answer (score 5):

reassign the replaced string to `s`

```
String s="Kathleen D'Souza";
s = s.replaceAll("'","''");
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try 
s= "test ' test";

```
`s.replaceAll("'","\"");`     => test " test

`s.replaceAll("'","''");`     => test '' test
```

Answer (score 0):

`Strings` are immutable. Assign the result of `replaceAll` to your `String`:

```
s = s.replaceAll("'","''");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s="Kathleen D'Souza";
s= s.replace("'", "''");
```

Try String#replace(). It will replace all occurrence of single ' with double ''.

Answer (score 0):

Note, with the given solutions successive single quotes will be doubled, so Kathleen D''Souza turns into Kathleen D''''Souza.  (I've seen users outsmart themselves like this.) If that is something you are concerned about, you can match successive single quotes with:

```
 s = s.replaceAll("''*","''");
```